# ML Model: Stock market price prediction model

Tags: regression, pca, prediction

I got asked this in an interview. "If you had a lot of data about a lot of stocks, how would you go about predicting the next price of a stock?" "What are advantages and disadvantages of using certain models/strategies?"

The question seemed intentionally so open-ended, but I didn't know how to approach it. With some more thinking, I feel like one approach is to break stocks up by sector, since different sectors may have different relationships. Then, I could use PCA in order to reduce the dimensionality of the data, and then use regression in order to predict prices. What do people think are other, better solutions?

Comment: You're correct that these kinds of questions are deliberately open-ended; however, the open-endedness of them does not make them great candidates for stats.SE because there is no correct answer. More information about which questions are on-topic here can be found in the [help].

Answer (score 2):

I would more likely, in an interview context, give an answer of linking a stock's price to the expected performance of a sector.

For example, in the case of a pandemic, telecommunications applications would likely benefit. How has a stock in question, within this sector performed relative to the sector average?

So, based on one model of how a particular sector would likely benefit under a presumed scenario, followed by a more traditional relative performance statistical analysis at the sector level, I might be comfortable (or at least, the interviewer might feel so) so as to provide a projection of a stock price change within the time frame consistent with the first model.

The advantages of this approach are that it logically integrates current macro conditions (importantly for projecting trends) and separately makes quality decisions on stock differentiation within the sector.

Good luck on your next interview.